# Graphical test of the correctness of an implementation

Tags: python

I'm testing the implementation of an [algorithm](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3787) calculating the overlap area of two ellipsis.

The idea of the test is to check **visually** whether or not the intersection points of the ellipses (if any) are calculated correctly. If this is not the case, then the calculated area cannot be correct.

**EDIT**: The output of my implementation is a file with the intersection points. I plot the ellipses and the intersection points and `savefig` them. Visually I check the results and convince myself if the intersection points are correct.

Here is  one example:

[image]

My problem is simply this visual method doesn't scale with increasing number of tests (let's say 1000 cases).

Any ideas how to automate this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach**

Decided to post this as another answer since I took a completely fresh approach. I used the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) to draw two ellipses on different images with the colors red and green. I then blended the two images and counted the number of yellow pixels in the image, yellow being the composite of green and red and will become the color of the intersection area. The first ellipse will be colored red, the second green, their intersection yellow. For demonstration purposes I made the second ellipse a circle and made it fully contained in the first so that one could show it's area should be the area of a circle that size. Because of pixels being counted one won't get a precise answer but in this example with a resolution of 500x500 the pixel count area was 0.42% from the correct value. Of course if you increase the resolution you can expect to get more precision, but for testing purposes I would just accept a tolerance of +/- 1%. You can comment the lines out that save and show the image I've just included them to assist in initial debugging.

**Performance**

I ran a test run of calling the function 1,000 times and it finished in 13.4 seconds. So it takes about 13 milliseconds to create the three images and do a pixel count which isn't bad performance for the task at hand.

**Code**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from math import pi

RED, GREEN, YELLOW = (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (127, 127, 0)
SIZE = (500, 500)

def overlap(ellipse1, ellipse2):
    im1 = Image.new("RGB", SIZE)
    ImageDraw.Draw(im1).ellipse(ellipse1, fill=RED)
    im2 = Image.new("RGB", SIZE)
    ImageDraw.Draw(im2).ellipse(ellipse2, fill=GREEN)
    im3 = Image.blend(im1, im2, 0.5)
    im3.show()
    im3.save('test.png', "png")
    return [count for count, color in im3.getcolors() if color == YELLOW][0]

area1 = overlap((0, 50, 500, 450), (50, 50, 450, 450))
area2 = pi * (200**2)
print "overlap calc:" , area1
print "exact area:  " , area2
print "percent diff:" , ((area1 - area2)/area2)*100
```

**Output**

```
overlap calc: 126196
exact area:   125663.706144
percent diff: 0.423585992124
```

**Image**

[image: ellipse with intersection]

Comment: Your idea is great! Thanks for the efforts. The coordinates of the ellipse are in [Pixel] I guess, right? Besides, `ellipse()` gets the coordinates of the bounding box. So intuitively I would ask it is possible to convert a `(x, y, a, b, phi)` tuple in real world coordinates in this image coordinates. Not sure how to pass the argument `phi`. In the help you just get the following header definition `ellipse(self, xy, fill=None, outline=None)`, but how is `xy` defined?

Comment: That is correct the coordinates are in pixels. The docs are a little sparse but the python image library is heavily used in the community, so you can find a lot of examples on google, and easily get answers on stackoverflow. The box coordinates it accepts are x1, y1, x2, y2 which defines the top left and bottom right coordinates of the containing box. Now if you want to apply phi on the ellipse you can call the rotate method on the image with the exact angle you want to apply. You could also post a question on stackoverflow saying how does one implement (x, y, a, b, phi) using PIL.

Comment: Thanks! I found some answers  [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/image-draw.html). I'll make some research before asking the community. Again, thanks for the good idea.

Comment: @Tengis No worries, I enjoyed working on it. It's the first time I work on a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

So I did a bit of research and this is what I recommend. What you can do is use another python library to calculate the intersection points of the two ellipses and then compare that two what your implementation returns. The two should be identical if not you can have the test fail and investigate which one was wrong. The [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/geometry.html) library can calculate the intersection points between a number of supported entities Ellipse, Circle, Polygon, RegularPolygon, Triangle. I recommend using the standard library's [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) to perform the actual tests. Then you could run a test run that creates a few thousand random ellipses and checks the intersection points of each.

You can have a look at this [example code in their docs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/geometry.html#example-usage) that includes an intersection calculation. They have this amazing feature in their docs where you can click on the Run code block in SymPy Live link next to the example and it will open a python session in your browser and run that example on their google app engine servers. This lets you take their library for a test drive without having to install it on your machine. Check out their [web-based interactive python shell](http://live.sympy.org/) it's really neat.

Comment: I actually uses boost-geometry to check the results. The sympy is cool but is immature (as they said). So I'm not sure if I can trust their routines.

Comment: maybe you can try the same approach then with boost-geometry, that is using unit tests and randomly generated ellipses.

Comment: With boost-geometry I m comparing with overlapping area of two polygons (20 sided ~ ellipse). So In principle this should tell if I have a blunder in the code, but never if my results are < some eps.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Sorry I think I've misunderstand the question.
To do that you need to find the intersections between 2 elipse function
Or you can uses sympy http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/geometry.html

Comment: Yes the tests are implemented in python. I don't get the point with `xlim` and `ylim`. I want to check if the green o's in the graph  are really intersection points or not. IMHO Nothing to do with max and min. Please give more explanations what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: I see. Sorry I don't really understand the question :(
Maybe this can help:http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2011/05/hot-to-find-intersection-of-two.html